# Set an inherited property in a sub-class via MEF import

Tags: c#, mef

I am trying to set an inherited property in a sub-class via MEF import. The base class declares a property, but does not specify an import. Multiple sub-classes should then import into this property - each using its own import specification.

This is illustrated below:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public SomeType SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    [Import(...)] // declaring a new property and importing here is easy
    public AnotherType AnotherProperty { get; set; }

    // how can I MEF import into the inherited SomeProperty?
}
```

The only solutions I found are:

1. make SomeProperty virtual in the BaseClass and re-declare/overwrite it in the sub-class. This has the disadvantage of potentially duplicating code in sub-classes. I do not actually want to re-declare the property, just specify an import
2. wrap SomeProperty with another property in the sub-class which essentially does a pass-through of the setter and import into that. That seems pretty ugly.
3. use a constructor with corresponding import-attributes on the sub-class which sets SomeProperty. This is not an ideal approach if the number of properties to be inherited and set this way grows larger.

Any help or ideas for a simple and clean approach would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is always option to use [RegistrationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.registration.registrationbuilder), I'm sure you will find usage examples on Web.

Basically, it allows you to decouple specification of the export/import from the classes/types you create. In your case:

- Skpi declaring imports in the base class
- When creating part catalogs (or composing parts), you shall specify [RegistrationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.registration.registrationbuilder) (e.g. see ccor of [TypeCatalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.typecatalog) that accepts [ReflectionContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.reflectioncontext) from which [ReflectionContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.reflectioncontext) inherits) that adds expected imports on per-implementing type basis